# I'm creating a Rock, Paper, Scissors game that is designed to go through however many simulations the user inputs into a text box

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Like the title says, I'm creating a Rock, Paper, Scissors game in **visual basic 2010** that is designed to go through however many simulations the user inputs into a text box, the thing is though, i enter what ever number and the amount of times the computer, the player, and ties displays correctly, the program is only displaying the data needed for two out of the three test boxes that were purposely set up as to only be viewed instead of as editable for the first three choices on the radio button selection.

This is what the program looks like visually.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CL0J.png)

Here is what the program looks like through code assigned to the play button that i have coded so far.

```
 'variables for rock, paper, and scissors
    Const rock As Integer = 0
    Const paper As Integer = 1
    Const scissors As Integer = 2



    'variables for the result text boxes
    Dim intPlayerWins As Integer = 0
    txtPlayerWins.Text = intPlayerWins.ToString
    Dim intCompWins As Integer = 0
    txtComputerWins.Text = intCompWins.ToString
    Dim intTies As Integer = 0
    txtTies.Text = intTies.ToString

    'result percentages
    Dim dblPlayerPerc As Double = 0
    txtPlayWinPercent.Text = dblPlayerPerc.ToString
    Dim dblCompPerc As Double = 0
    txtCompWinPercent.Text = dblCompPerc.ToString
    Dim dblTiesPerc As Double = 0
    txtTiesPercent.Text = dblTiesPerc.ToString

    'variables for computer selection summary
    Dim dblRock As Double = 0
    txtRock.Text = dblRock.ToString
    Dim dblPaper As Double = 0
    txtPaper.Text = dblPaper.ToString
    Dim dblScissors As Double = 0
    txtScissors.Text = dblScissors.ToString

    'Simulations
    Dim intSimulations As Integer
    Try
        intSimulations = CInt(txtSimulations.Text)

    Catch ex As Exception

        Return

    End Try

    'playerChoice
    Dim playerChoice As Integer



    If radRock.Checked = True Then
        playerChoice = rock

    End If

    If radPaper.Checked = True Then
        playerChoice = paper

    End If

    If radScissors.Checked = True Then
        playerChoice = scissors

    End If

    'Random number
    Dim rand As New Random


    'random button is selected
    If radRandom.Checked = True Then
        playerChoice = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 2))

    End If

    'test of program/computerChoice
    Dim computerChoice As Integer

    For intcount As Integer = 1 To intSimulations Step 1
        computerChoice = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 2))


        'Decision structure
        If playerChoice = rock Then
            If computerChoice = rock Then
                intTies += 1
                dblRock += 1
            End If
            If computerChoice = paper Then
                intCompWins += 1
                dblPaper += 1
            End If
            If computerChoice = scissors Then
                intPlayerWins += 1
                dblScissors += 1
            End If

        End If

        If playerChoice = paper Then
            If computerChoice = rock Then
                intPlayerWins += 1
                dblRock += 1
            End If
            If computerChoice = paper Then
                intTies += 1
                dblPaper += 1
            End If
            If computerChoice = scissors Then
                intCompWins += 1
                dblScissors += 1
            End If

        End If

        If playerChoice = scissors Then
            If computerChoice = rock Then
                intCompWins += 1
                dblRock += 1
            End If
            If computerChoice = paper Then
                intPlayerWins += 1
                dblPaper += 1
            End If
            If computerChoice = scissors Then
                intTies += 1
                dblScissors += 1
            End If

        End If

    Next

    txtPlayerWins.Text = intPlayerWins.ToString
    txtComputerWins.Text = intCompWins.ToString
    txtTies.Text = intTies.ToString

    MessageBox.Show("Program was sucessfull!")
```

Comment: Please provide your code and your output, so we can help you.

Comment: And you really think that without a trace of code someone is going to assemble a helpful answer from their crystal ball?

Comment: I edited/fixed my original questions.